# git-svn on mac can't connect to remote svn repository, while simple svn can

Tags: git, macos, svn, homebrew

So I just switched to mac and wanted to continue to work at my project. I use git-svn on my side. It worked perfectly on my linux machine, but on mac I am getting this error:

```
$ git svn init -s svn://some/remote/svn-repo Initialized empty Git 
repository in /Users/..../.git/ Can't create session: Unable to connect 
to a repository at URL 'svn://some/remote/svn-repo' at 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/perl/Git/SVN.pm 
line 310.
```

And simple svn checkout works fine. Git and svn were installed with `$ brew install git subversion`

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not much of a svn wizard but have some experience with git-svn. Let's go with the basics. You are specifying (with -s) that it's standard layout. What is the output of `svn ls svn://some/remote/svn-repo`? I guess it's some piece of information you can add to the original question.